# Analysis question limit at infinity $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \cos(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

1_I have questions about that when is it necessary to use bounding for limit problems  e.g.
this limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
solution is zero because $|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)|\leq 1$ times zero becomes zero. But I wonder if I have this limit instead $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \cos(n)$$ can I bound it like this $|\cos(n)|\leq 1$ and $|(-1^n)|=1$ and the result becomes one?

2_When should someone use bounding rule when someone evaluate a limit problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bound $|{(-1)}^n|=1$.  You can't take the absolute value like you can with $\sin{x}$ or $\cos{x}$.  The limit does not exist because $\lim_{n \to \infty} {(-1)}^n$ could be $1$ or $-1$.  Since $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \cos{x} \neq 0$, the limit could take on any value from $[-1,1]$ therefore it does not exist.

Comment: Well you **can** bound it, but you just end up with $|a_n|\le 1$ which says nothing about convergence. Your wording is a bit misleading.

Comment: thank you I wonder let us say that lim of cos(x) is = 0  for a moment then in this case could the solution of lim n->infinity of (-1)^n *cos(n) becomes zero ? why?

Comment: Because $-1 \cdot 0=0$ and $1 \cdot 0=0$.  If you have taken multivariable calculus, the way I think about these types of limits is that every path must equal the same number for the limit to converge.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example works and you can conclude that

$$\left|x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\le|x|\to0.$$

However, the same approach doesn't work in the second problem. While it is true that $|\cos(n)|\le 1$, it turns out that this limit doesn't exist because $(-1)^n$ alternates between $1$ and $-1$. Note $(-1)^n$ is $1$ for even $n$ and $-1$ for odd $n$. So $(-1)^n\cos(n)$ is $\cos(n)$ for even $n$ and $-\cos(n)$ for odd $n$. Therefore, if $a_n = (-1)^n\cos(n)$, then $a_{2n} = \cos(n)$ and $a_{2n+1} = -\cos(n)$. Since the subsequences $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ have different limits ($\lim a_{2n} = \cos(n)$ and $\lim a_{2n+1} = -\cos(n)$), the limit $\lim a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you but sin(x) also oscillate from [-1 to 1] why sometimes we bound it and sometimes we say that limit of sin(x) doesn't exist I don't know when I should say that the limit of sin(x) doesn't exist and when to bound it ? why we could bound sin(x) and not -1^n they both oscillate ?

Comment: Both $|\sin(x)|\le 1$ and $|\cos(x)|\le 1$ so they are bounded. However, $(-1)^n$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$. So, the problem isn't that $(-1)^n$ isn't bounded (it is since $|(-1)^n|=1$). The problem is that  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n$ doesn't exist. The sequence $-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,\ldots$ never approaches a single number. So, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \sin(n),\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n \cos(n)$, etc. don't exist as we can find two subsequences which converge to a different number.